# Strange Wi-Fi Problem

Tags: wireless

I have strange Wi-Fi problem. All my devices were properly fine but suddenly only Ubuntu installed laptops has stopped to connect our wifi. One laptop is totally outdated, never upgraded, Ubuntu 11.xx. The other one is always updated. And none of them can't establish the wifi connection. But outdated Ubuntu installed laptop has dual boot with win 7 and win 7 can establish the connection.

Here is output of `wireless_script.sh` from updated laptop: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10683087/

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you try (as super-user) `modprobe -r iwlwifi && modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1` ([source](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/137034/47852)))? What's the command output and can you connect afterwards?

Comment: I did try but it didnt work @DavidFoerster

http://paste.ubuntu.com/10683524/

Comment: Did the command, I supplied, work? What are the current module parameters of `iwlwifi`? Is `11n_disable` set to 1 (check with `modinfo iwlwifi`)?

Comment: Yes @DavidFoerster, i did the command and the output was above. Other output is:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/10683587/

Comment: Ok, thanks. That sounded like it was worth a try.

Comment: I also just tried to connect the wifi using wicd, but nothing changed.

Comment: I would try `sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi && sleep 10 && sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=8` and see if you can connect.  The 11n_disable=1 disables 11n wireless while 11n_disable=8 enable agg TX in 11n and was needed on one of my laptops to connect to a N only network

Comment: I tried 11n_disable=8 by adding to iwlwifi.conf, the outputs were the same as above. Also, i tried to change the wifi mod separately 11b, 11g, 11n, 11b/g and 11b/g/n and it still  cant connect.

Comment: Did you reboot since adding 11n_disable=8?  On a couple of my laptops with intel cards I have to reboot as they won't connect after modprobe -r iwlwifi until rebooted

Comment: I didnot mention that but of course i rebooted. Somethings slightly has changed in syslog, here is the output: 
http://paste.ubuntu.com/10688326/

Answer (score 1):

add this option in kernel drivers settings

```
echo options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1 | tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

Then restart the system this must fix wifi problem.

Comment: I fixed your command. `sudo echo ... >> /etc/...` doesn't work like that.

Comment: This solution doesn't help though, as one can infer from the back and forth between OP and me in the comments to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I changed the modem with same model and everything is fine.